# How would I use the radio button in jswing to make a listener capable of placing an S or O in the given cell depending on what is selected?

Tags: java, swing

```
package SOS;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BoardPanel {
    private JFrame frame;

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTopPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createBoard(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) source;
            String text = textField.getText();
            int dimension = Integer.parseInt(text);
            JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(dimension, dimension));
            for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
                    JLabel square = new JLabel("   ");
                    square.setBackground(Color.white);
                    square.setOpaque(true);
                    square.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    board.add(square);
                }
            }
            frame.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
        }
    }

    private JPanel createTopPanel() {
        
         JRadioButton optionS = new JRadioButton("S");
         JRadioButton optionO = new JRadioButton("O");
         
         ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
         group.add(optionS);
         group.add(optionO);
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Board size:");
        topPanel.add(label);
        JTextField boardSize = new JTextField(6);
        boardSize.addActionListener(this::createBoard);
        topPanel.add(boardSize);
        topPanel.add(optionS, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        topPanel.add(optionO, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return topPanel;
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new BoardPanel().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

I know I am supposed to make an action listener for each radio button and that seems pretty straightforward, but I am confused on how I would do that and then translate that to placing an S or O on the game boards given cell depending on what is selected. I think the more confusing part is being able to draw in the given cell either the S or the O depending on what is selected. This is for an SOS game, sort of like tic tac toe. I tried following a simple tic tac toe example but got lost as there is no radio buttons like this and I am using a different createboard method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your radioButton globally so you can check the selected status. Then in a listener in your cells check that and place the appropriate letter:

```
package SOS;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BoardPanel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JRadioButton optionS;
    private JRadioButton optionO;

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createTopPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createBoard(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) source;
            String text = textField.getText();
            int dimension = Integer.parseInt(text);
            JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(dimension, dimension));
            for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
                    JLabel square = new JLabel("   ");
                    square.setBackground(Color.white);
                    square.setOpaque(true);
                    square.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    board.add(square);
                    square.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            square.setText(optionS.isSelected() ? " S " : " O ");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            frame.getContentPane().add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
        }
    }

    private JPanel createTopPanel() {

        optionS = new JRadioButton("S");
        optionO = new JRadioButton("O");

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(optionS);
        group.add(optionO);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Board size:");
        topPanel.add(label);
        JTextField boardSize = new JTextField(6);
        boardSize.addActionListener(this::createBoard);
        topPanel.add(boardSize);
        topPanel.add(optionS, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        topPanel.add(optionO, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return topPanel;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new BoardPanel().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: errr this isnt really what I am wanting is it? wouldnt this just set the board size to S or O which isnt what I want. The board size works good as is and is resizing good.

Comment: You only have 1 textfield in your frame, it's really unclear then what you want to achieve.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with texfields, it has to do with the board and being able to place an S or an O on the given cell depending on what is selected like i stated.

Comment: What triggers the place of the letter? A click on a cell?

Comment: Its basically supposed to be like tic tac toe, where you can select S or O and then depending on which you have selected you would be able to place down an S or an O in the selected square. kinda complicated in theory

Comment: yea where you click it would place it, but thats the part im stuck on right now in terms of how i would do that along w the listener in the radio button

Comment: Check if the updated answer helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was wanting. Sorry for being confusing at first. Really appreciate you working with me through it. Im just not good at java and jswing lmao

Comment: Great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you might be able to do this, personally, I like to decouple the workflows and remove dependencies where I can.

For example, your `createBoard` method is making an assumption about how the `dimension` value is captured by the user.  What happens if you want to change that workflow to use a `JSpinner` or `JCombobox`?  You'd then have to modify this method as well.

Better to pass the method the information it needs to do its job.  In fact, I'd make it return an instance of `JPanel`, so as to remove all the dependencies, after all `createBoard` should do just that, nothing else.

I've changed the workflow so there is now a dedicated "create" button, this will collect the information it needs in order to be able to create the board itself.  Not as dynamic as the other approach, but it gives the user time to consider their inputs

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BoardPanel {

    private JFrame frame;

    enum State {
        S, O;
    }

    private JPanel board;

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTopPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createBoard(int dimension, State state) {
        JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(dimension, dimension));
        for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
                JLabel square = new JLabel("  " + state.name() + "  ");
                square.setBackground(Color.white);
                square.setOpaque(true);
                square.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                board.add(square);
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    private JPanel createTopPanel() {
        JRadioButton optionS = new JRadioButton("S");
        JRadioButton optionO = new JRadioButton("O");
        JTextField boardSize = new JTextField(6);
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(optionS);
        group.add(optionO);

        // Default state
        optionS.setSelected(true);

        JButton createButton = new JButton("Make it so");
        createButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                State state = State.O;
                if (optionS.isSelected()) {
                    state = State.S;
                }
                try {
                    int dimension = Integer.parseInt(boardSize.getText());
                    if (board != null) {
                        frame.remove(board);
                    }
                    board = createBoard(dimension, state);
                    frame.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.pack();
                } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(topPanel, "Invalid board size", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Board size:");
        topPanel.add(label);
        topPanel.add(boardSize);
        topPanel.add(optionS);
        topPanel.add(optionO);
        topPanel.add(createButton);

        return topPanel;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new BoardPanel().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

If you'd prefer something a little more dynamic, then you could add shared `ActionListener` to the buttons and text field, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BoardPanel {

    private JFrame frame;

    enum State {
        S, O;
    }

    private JPanel board;

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTopPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createBoard(int dimension, State state) {
        JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(dimension, dimension));
        for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
                JLabel square = new JLabel("  " + state.name() + "  ");
                square.setBackground(Color.white);
                square.setOpaque(true);
                square.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                board.add(square);
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    private JPanel createTopPanel() {
        JRadioButton optionS = new JRadioButton("S");
        JRadioButton optionO = new JRadioButton("O");
        JTextField boardSize = new JTextField(6);
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(optionS);
        group.add(optionO);
        
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                State state = State.O;
                if (optionS.isSelected()) {
                    state = State.S;
                }
                try {
                    int dimension = Integer.parseInt(boardSize.getText());
                    if (board != null) {
                        frame.remove(board);
                    }
                    board = createBoard(dimension, state);
                    frame.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.pack();
                } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                    // Not yet ready
                }
            }
        };
        
        optionS.addActionListener(actionListener);
        optionO.addActionListener(actionListener);
        boardSize.addActionListener(actionListener);

        // Default state
        optionS.setSelected(true);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Board size:");
        topPanel.add(label);
        topPanel.add(boardSize);
        topPanel.add(optionS);
        topPanel.add(optionO);

        return topPanel;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new BoardPanel().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```